# Find the sum of the following series 3 - 3/2 + 3/4 - 3/8 + 3/16 - 3/32 + ...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is an alternating series, that looks like this:
[image: Alternating series]

I am given the series:
[image: Given series]

The book mentions the Alternating Series Estimation Theory, however it seems like there is a definite answer by the wording of the question.

Comment: hint: its a geometric sequence with $a_0=3$ and $q=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks, I was so caught up in the alternating series I didn't think to rewrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pulling out a factor of $3$, we see that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{3(-1)^n}{2^n} = 3\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{-1}2\right)^n\right) \,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
Now we have a geometric series of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n  = \dfrac1{1-x}$$
Plugging the above in $(\spadesuit)$, we obtain that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{3(-1)^n}{2^n} = 3\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{-1}2\right)^n\right) = 3 \cdot \dfrac1{1-(-1/2)} = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}\frac{3(-1)^n}{2^n} = 3\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n = 3\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(\left( \frac{-1}{2}\right)^m +2\right)\right) = \left( \frac{-1}{2}\right)^m +2
$$